# Loop regression forevery entity, save predicted values for all entities

Tags: r

My goal is to run a regression for all entities (loop), with variable "income" and "family.members" as independent variable, and save the predicted Y values for every entity given their level of "income" and "family.members". `That is lm(happiness~income + family.members, data=df1))` Ive tried my way around with group_by(), but the technical part is a bit over my level. Hope someone can help out!

Current data set

```
ID  Year  Happiness  income  members
11    1    3          34242   2
11    2    7          32321   4
31    1    1          24222   1
13    1    10         51231   5
31    2    3          12313   3
```

Goal

```
 ID  Year  Happiness  income  members  pred.happiness
 13   1    3          34242   2        3,2
 11   1    7          32321   4        4,2
 33   3    1          24222   1        3,4
 13   2    10         51231   5        3,2
 11   2    2          12313   3        3,2
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help you directly without data to work with. However, here is an example of a `nest()` method.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(modelr)


head(ChickWeight)
#>   weight Time Chick Diet
#> 1     42    0     1    1
#> 2     51    2     1    1
#> 3     59    4     1    1
#> 4     64    6     1    1
#> 5     76    8     1    1
#> 6     93   10     1    1

by_id <- ChickWeight %>% 
  group_by(Chick) %>% 
  nest()


lin <- function(df){
  lm(weight ~ Time,data = ChickWeight)
}

by_id <- by_id %>% mutate(model = map(data,lin))

by_id <- by_id %>% 
  mutate(pred = map2(data,model,modelr::add_predictions))

by_id
#> # A tibble: 50 x 4
#> # Groups:   Chick [50]
#>    Chick data              model  pred             
#>    <ord> <list>            <list> <list>           
#>  1 1     <tibble [12 × 3]> <lm>   <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  2 2     <tibble [12 × 3]> <lm>   <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  3 3     <tibble [12 × 3]> <lm>   <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  4 4     <tibble [12 × 3]> <lm>   <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  5 5     <tibble [12 × 3]> <lm>   <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  6 6     <tibble [12 × 3]> <lm>   <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  7 7     <tibble [12 × 3]> <lm>   <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  8 8     <tibble [11 × 3]> <lm>   <tibble [11 × 4]>
#>  9 9     <tibble [12 × 3]> <lm>   <tibble [12 × 4]>
#> 10 10    <tibble [12 × 3]> <lm>   <tibble [12 × 4]>
#> # … with 40 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

See [Many Models](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html) by Hadley for more info.

Good luck!